# Django display multiple models in single template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How to do the same for detail view?

views.py

```
class ViewProfile(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'profile/profile_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ViewProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['profile'] = Profile.objects.all()
        return ctx
```

profile_view.html

```
<h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
{% for profile in profile %}
<p>{{ profile.full_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to display only the first in the list as detail view. any methods?

Comment: You've given the iterated variable the same name as the iterator, just make them different

Comment: i am beginner.. can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

You've given the iterated variable the same name as the iterator, just make them different

```
{% for prof in profile %}
<p>{{ prof.full_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i am not displaying a list. it is a single item. for loop is used only for list view right? currently iam adding slice to get the first item only.

Comment: You've already added `profile` to your context data, a for loop is for iterable data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [first() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#first) on queryset

**views.py**

```
class ViewProfile(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'profile/profile_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ViewProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #  profile in your context will contain only the first profile
        ctx['profile'] = Profile.objects.all().first() 
        return ctx
```

**profile_view.html**

```
<h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
<p>{{ profile.full_name }}</p>
```

You can also used [order_by() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) to change the order of your queryset.